# Event on of jquery?

Tags: jquery, events

```
$('body').on('click', '.conversation_item', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("go");

});
$('body').on('click', '.conversation_item > span', function () {
    console.log("true");
});
```

when i click element .conversation_item > span jquery active both **conversation_item** and **conversation_item > span**  . I don't want it but I must use **on** event. Help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **[event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)** on click event

```
$('body').on('click', '.conversation_item > span', function (e) {
 e.stopPropagation()
  alert("true");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ggsbobbc/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop **[event propagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)** to child element click:

```
$('body').on('click', '.conversation_item > span', function (event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
   console.log("true");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should stop event propagation. Check this out.

http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/